# Logo in the footer section need to be turn into thier contrast color

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, footer

my footer is dark and github logo is also black, yeah that black github logo in footer that partially visible but when cursor move over thir it goes invisible

if move cursor on that github logo it should be turn into their contrast color like get it into white

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you have integrated the git-hub logo but what you describe is the hover, you should inspect the code, look for the class that gives the hover to the logo and change the color to one that you like more

Comment: filter: brightness(100%);
for adding this, it changes I think

Comment: You must share the html and css code or some reproducible example, if not my hands are tied, I lack information